# How is Cartesian coordinate system related to his philosophy

Tags: analytic-geometry, math-history, philosophy

In 1637, Rene Descartes published his famous monograph about philosophy "*Discourse on the Method of reasoning well and Seeking Truth in the Sciences*", and analytic method of geometry has been come up with in the appendices. I want to know is there any philosophical thinking or method leading to his invention of coordinate system? Which philosophical rule led him to connect numbers with geometry?

Answer (score 2):

For a detailed but very readable discussion of this and related questions about the connection between Descartes' philosophy and his mathematics, and about the wider historical context, see the freely available

> *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* entry on [Descartes' Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-mathematics/)

The general standard of *SEP* entries, and the standard of entries related to logic and the philosophy of mathematics in particular, is extraordinarily high: and though I'm no historian, this strikes me as no exception.

Answer (score 1):

For more details, you can supplement *SEP*'s entry with the book-lenght study :

> Chikara Sasaki, [Descartes' Mathematical Thought](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402017464) (2003).

All first part (about 150 pages) is devoted to the historical background of D's studies (which forms the bulk of *SEP*'s entry) but you can see Ch.4 : **THE MATHEMATICAL BACKGROUND OF THE** *REGULAE AD DIRECTIONEM INGENII* (page 159-on).

This unpublished [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_for_the_Direction_of_the_Mind) contains a (failed) attempt to develop a [Mathesis universalis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathesis_universalis), i.e. a general method to "analyze" all problems, and not only mathematical ones [see Sasaki, page 190-on].

Ch.5 of Sasaki's book is devoted to : **THE** *GéOMéTRIE* **OF 1637** [page 205-on].

Clues of the hidden links between the "thin" *rules of method* of the [Discours de la méthode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_on_the_Method) and the [Géométrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie) must be searched into the *Regulae*.